# Pandas: Replacing a row with another data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames: df1

[image: Data frame 1 :df1]

and df2

[image: Data frame 2: df2]

Now I want to replace one of rows of df1 (highlighted in red colour) with all values of df2. I try with following codes but didn't give the desired result. Here is the code:

```
df1[df1['Category_2']=='Specified Functionality'].update(df2)
```

I also tried:

```
df1[df1['Category_2']=='Specified Functionality'] = df2
```

Could anyone guide me where I am making the mistake?

Comment: Can you please post the actual data as text instead of pictures of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the rows like this:

```
row = 13
df2 = df2.rename(columns = {'Functionality': 'Category_2')
df = pd.concat([df1[0:row], df2, df1[row+1:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
```